# Windows 8 phone Browsing to url giving error c#

Tags: c#, url, windows-phone-8, browser

Whenever I search to this URL the Web Browser Component says that it is invalid. Why does this happen when it is a perfectly okay url.

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.en.m.wikipedia.org", UriKind.Absolute));
```

or

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.en.m.facebook.org", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the protocol or it doesn't know how to create it.

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.en.m.wikipedia.org", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Comment: I have made the edit, but it still says that they are invalid urls and go to the bt address book.

Comment: I assumed "Browser" was the name of a web browser control you have on your page and that is how I ran my test.  Is this correct?  Are you using the new 8.1 or the older 8.0 frameowrk?  What exactly is coming up when you run it with the protocol added?  Is it the exact url you have given or are you doing something diffrent in your app that you are generalizinig here?

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1, using the WebBrowser tool and when navigating to sites with .m. it says it is a invalid url. But when I search in google and go to the facebook link, it can navigate to this website and then I copy this url and navigate directly to it, the invalid url error message pops up. @Bryan Roberts

Comment: Did you double check that your app has the "internet" capability in the Package.appxmanifest?  My tests on device and emulator show this working fine now that the protocol is included.